# The position of the word, ‘simply’

Tags: grammar, word-usage

1. He simply told her that he worked for the Corporation.
2. He told her that he worked for the corporation simply.

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

The question is how "simply" affects the sentence.

> He simply told her that he worked for the Corporation.

This is vaguely similar to "He only told her" and "He merely told her".

In this case, "simply" is referring to (all) his actions, and among (all) these actions he simply only did one thing: "He told her".   Nothing else.

> He told her that he worked for the corporation simply.

No, that would not be said.

---

There are other options though:

> He told her that he simply worked for the corporation...

and

> He told her simply that he worked for the corporation...

These choices are possible, but they require more surrounding context to make sense.
The first one implies that maybe he was doing other things for the corporation, and he is saying that's not the case. He simply works there. The second one implies he might have said more, but he chose not to.